# Estrutura de documentos

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

Olá, estou começando a aprender MongoDB, e tenho uma dúvida que não encontrei em nenhum lugar:

Os documentos de uma mesma coleção podem ter estrutura diferentes.
Exemplo:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": 30,
    "isBlocked": false
}
```

Tendo em uma mesma coleção diferentes objetos JSON, isso pode ocasionar muitos problemas? Por exemplo, na hora de lidar/filtrar dados, etc.

É um erro ter coleções com diferentes objetos JSON?

Agradeço quem me elucidar essa questão, meu pensamento ainda está muito voltado ao SQL tradicional.

Valeu.

Comment: Eu acho um erro dentro de uma coleção ter diversos tipos de documentos, manter um padrão pode futuramente evitar problemas.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no título removendo a tag mongodb, para que fique somente nas tags.